# Java - HashSet best way to implement iterator that does not support remove()

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a class which uses a `HashSet` and I want the class implement `Iterable`, I do not, however, want the class iterator to support the `remove()` method.

The default iterator of `HashSet` is `HashSet.KeyIterator` which is a private class within the    `HashSet` class, so I cannot simply extend it and override the remove method.

Ideally I would like to avoid writing a wrapper class for `KeyIterator`, but I am at a loss as to how else I could easily and simply implement my own iterator in any other way.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: Does your HashSet need to be modifiable?

Comment: @Kevin Yes but it also must maintain a consistent number of elements, which is managed by the class's internal logic but not something I would like to leave to trust if the HashSet is modified using the iterator.

Comment: What's so bad about a wrapper?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet(myHashSet).iterator();
```

Comment: Just be aware that the iterator will return throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if you try to modify the Set through it.

Comment: Right. If you want an iterator that silently ignores calls to remove(), you'll have to go with one of the other solutions.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` is a thin wrapper.  Changes to myHashSet directly will still be reflected in the unmodifiable collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache Commons Collections, you can use [org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.UnmodifiableIterator](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/UnmodifiableIterator.html)
:

```
UnmodifiableIterator.decorate(set.iterator());
```

Guava (Google Collections) also has an UnmodifiableIterator, which supports generics: [`com.google.common.collect.UnmodifiableIterator<E>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator.html) Usage:

```
Iterators.unmodifiableIterator(set.iterator());
```

Comment: Note, that apache collections don't support generics.

Comment: But it provides a good example, how to implement something like that... :-)

Comment: ...or you can look at `com.google.common.collect.UnmodifiableIterator<E>`

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way that we can avoid those kind of exceptions while removing elements from the iterator

```
List<String> results=new ArrayList<String>() //a collection
Iterator<String> itr=results.iterator();
List<String> toBeRemoved=new ArrayList<String>();

while(itr.hasNext()){
   if(condiation){
      tobeRemoved.add(itr.next);

     }
}
//now we can remove unnecessary elements form the iterator
results.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
```

This kind of implementations is guarantee that no exceptions at modifying iterator

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern): create a new implementation of the `Iterator` interface that is a wrapper around the iterator from the `HashSet`, but instead of passing through calls to `remove` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: A valid answer but I explicitly asked for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Peter You're right. I apparently fail at reading comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the wrapper using an anonymous inner  class is fairly simple:

See this example:

```
package some;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

class MyIterable<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    private Set<E> internalSet = new HashSet<E>();

    public MyIterable( E ... all ) {
        for( E e : all ){
            internalSet.add( e );
        }
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        final Iterator<E> i = internalSet.iterator();
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            public boolean hasNext(){
                return i.hasNext();
            }
            public E next(){
                return i.next();
            }
            public void remove(){
                //you may throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    // Test it
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        Iterable<String> iterable = new MyIterable<String>("a", "b", "a", "b");

        System.out.println("Trying to invoke: remove");
        for(Iterator<String> iterator = iterable.iterator();
                                        iterator.hasNext();
                                        iterator.remove() ){
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Used in foreach");
        for( String s : iterable ){
            System.out.println( s );
        }

    }
}
```

You may also throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if you want to explicitly declare that the operation is not supported, but It may be a little excessive.